# Division by zero in crosstab formula

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I have a crosstab with a formula field. The query returns something like

```
 CategoryID   Company       MarketValue   PaymentMode
  1            ABC             1000         H
  1            xyz             2000         H
  3            efg             9800         H
```

Payment mode is half yearly indicated by 'H'
I made a formula field to evaluate payment mode by

```
WhileReadingRecords;
numberVar mode;  
         if({PaymentMode}='H') then mode:=2 else mode:=12
```

Then I made another formula field

```
WhileReadingRecords;
numberVar mode;
numberVar result:={MarketValue}/mod;
result
```

However it returns division by zero error. Why is my formula for Payment Mode not evaluating properly. I tried placing the payment mode formula in report head and cross tab is 2nd header but it still throws the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems.

First syntax error - or rather typo here, last 'e' is missing :)

```
numberVar result:={MarketValue}/mode;
```

Second - you need to evaluate formuals in specified order. Say your first formula has name 'calc_mode', then second one should start with next statement:

```
EvaluateAfter({@calc_mode});
```

Comment: Thanks Arvo, EvaluateAfter() fixed the problem for me =)

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad you already found Arvo's answer, but I have a few suggestions to simplify your code:

1. **Mode** is a buit-in Crystal function (see Crystal's help files).  So when I saw you using that word as the name for a custom variable, my brain did a backflip.  How about calling it "numPayPeriods" instead?
2. Since your sample formula includes field values, Crystal implements **WhileReadingRecords** by default (again, see Crystal's help files). So adding it is redundant in this case.  You can take that out entirely.
3. There's no need for 2 separate formulae in your example.  Also, your **Result** variable is unnecessary in Crystal syntax. You can simplify the whole thing to just 1 formula:

   `if({PaymentMode}='H') then

   {MarketValue}/2

   else

   {MarketValue}/12;`

Comment: Hey PowerUser. Thanks a lot for all that info & useful tips. I made a separate variable and placed it in report header because I thought it would evaluate again and again for every record. You are probably right about the variable name part because I was having zero for some rows for some odd reason I could not figure out. With fellows like you, stackoverflow is such a great place to hang with. Thank you so much again,  Damien.

Comment: It becomes a little hard sometimes to understand crystal's processing without a built in debugger.

Comment: Thanks, Damien.  BTW, it does have a built-in compiler you can use to debug.  When you either save a formula or use Alt-C, you'll get a pop-up of any compilation errors.